# GeolocationModule, Unable to get current position, location is null - SDK 3.5.1 with Android 5.0.0

Tags: gps, geolocation, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have used this syntax to get Geo Location in my App,

```
Ti.Geolocation.purpose = 'location for Emojot';
Ti.Geolocation.Android.manualMode = false;
Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_HIGH;

Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {}
```

It was working fine until I updated to SDK 3.5.1 and Run it in Andorid 5.0.0 device. When I do that I get this error,

```
GeolocationModule: (KrollRuntimeThread) [9994,10307] Unable to get current position, location is null
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To fix Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled Always returns false on Android 6, add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Titanium cannot find GPS, thus it keeps returning false. add above line to fix issue.